# JQuery .on() function with coffescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

im new to stackoverflow and will like to know if you could help me with the .on() function using coffescript.. im tyring to migrate the .live() cause i want everything as is supposed to be

```
$('#employee-select')

  .live('click', () ->
    if (!$('#employee-search-panel').is(':visible'))
      employeeLiveSearch()
      $('#employee-search-panel').slideDown()
    else
      $('#employee-search-panel').slideUp()
    end

  )
```

what i have came up with is

```
$(document)

  .on('click', '#employee-select',() ->
    if (!$('#employee-search-panel').is(':visible'))
      employeeLiveSearch()
      $('#employee-search-panel').slideDown()
    else
      $('#employee-search-panel').slideUp()
    end

  )
```

mi question is.... Is this the correct solution? doing the document and then adding the selector next to the 'click?

Regards

Comment: if its working its correct simple rule of thumb... consider posting your question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes that is correct.. however performancewise it is always better to use the static parent element available in document then the document itself..

```
 $(document) .on('click', '#employee-select',function(){ //<--- replace document with closest static parentelement
   if (!$('#employee-search-panel').is(':visible'))
     employeeLiveSearch()
     $('#employee-search-panel').slideDown()
  else
     $('#employee-search-panel').slideUp()
  end

})
```

[links](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about `on` event

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct as you written it, That is the way to `delegate the event to the existing parent item` in the page.

Although you can try to delegate to the `closest existing parent` which is available during dom initialized.

like which holds the `'#employee-select'` (*`parent of this elem`*):

```
$('parent of this').on('click', '#employee-select',() ->
```

Although `(document)` is the parent of all elem in the page so that would work absolutely fine.

```
$(document).on('click', '#employee-select',() ->
```